# Apache HTTP client with sdk 23 and proguard

Tags: java, android, apache, android-studio, proguard

Now many libraries requare compileSdkVersion 23. But this version not contains apache and some old libraries used apache http. For using apache with 23 I found  solution, where says about adding org.apache.http.legacy to grudle.
`useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`

this work. But not with proguard.
I use proguard for minify apk size, i'm not use obfuscation, only `minifyEnabled true`
in 'proguard-rules.txt' I have only one string:
`-dontobfuscate`
And when I build apk AndroidStudio show errors, because some libraries used apache. I tried to add keep classes to proguard but this not works. every time I got errors about apache.

```
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**

-keep class android.net.http.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.net.http.**

-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v4.** { *; }
```

Note: when proguard is disabled (**minifyEnabled** set to **false**) then apk build and work success. 
This is exaple of error from android studio console:

```
:app:proguardRelease
Warning: com.vk.sdk.api.httpClient.VKHttpOperation: can't find referenced method 'org.apache.http.HttpResponse execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest)' in program class com.vk.sdk.api.httpClient.VKHttpClient
Warning: org.acra.ErrorReporter: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification
```

and more

```
Warning: com.mopub.mobileads.VastVideoViewController: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning: com.mopub.mobileads.VastVideoViewController: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
Warning: com.mopub.mobileads.factories.HttpClientFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams
Warning: com.mopub.mobileads.factories.HttpClientFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams
Warning: com.mopub.mobileads.factories.HttpClientFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning: com.mopub.mobileads.factories.HttpClientFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning: com.mopub.mobileads.factories.HttpClientFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning: com.mopub.mobileads.factories.HttpClientFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning: com.mopub.mobileads.factories.HttpClientFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning: com.mopub.mobileads.util.HttpClients: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.mopub.mobileads.util.HttpClients: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.mopub.mobileads.util.HttpClients$1: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.mopub.mobileads.util.HttpClients$1: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.mopub.mobileads.util.HttpClients$1: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager
Warning: com.mopub.mobileads.util.HttpClients$1: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager
Warning: com.mopub.mobileads.util.HttpClients$1: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.mopub.mobileads.util.HttpClients$1: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.mopub.mobileads.util.vast.VastXmlManagerAggregator: can't find referenced class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
```

Comment: Not exactly the same error but probably the same cause: `compileSdkVersion 23` and `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` doesn't work properly with `minifyEnabled ture`. Still trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having the same problem, and solved it by:

- updating Android SDK Build Tools to 23.0.**1**
- updating MoPub to 3.13.0

Comment: I'm already have latest sdk 24.4 but this not help. Maybe I can update mopub, but I have more libraries which requare apache and I can't update it all.

Answer (score 0):

Got a similar problem with `google-play-services_lib`.
Solved in Eclipse by adding this line to proguard-project.txt:

```
-libraryjars "<path to sdk>\platforms\android-23\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar"
```

Same problem with the `setLatestEventInfo` method, it has been deprecated and removed in level 23. And this time there is no legacy jar.
So again, another line:

```
-libraryjars "<path to sdk>\platforms\android-22\android.jar"
```

With this reference, the first one for apache is probably superflous - I now only need the first, since an upgrade of google-play-services_lib to 8.2.98 version (although recent, still references apache).